# versionCodeOverride equivalent for Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, groovydsl

```
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            int newVersionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + abiVersionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0)

            output.versionCodeOverride = newVersionCode
        }
    }
```

I am trying to convert this Gradle Groovy DSL code to the new Gradle Kotlin DSL. I want the code to work exactly like it used to were APK splitted variant follows my versionCode pattern

This is what i have tried to write in Kotlin DSL:

```
    applicationVariants.all(object : Action<ApplicationVariant> {
        override fun execute(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
            variant.outputs.forEach {output ->
                val newVersionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode ?: 0 * 10 + abiVersionCodes[output.filters.first { it.identifier == com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI }]
                output.versionCodeOverride = newVersionCode
            }
        }
    })
```

But it says: "Unresolved reference: versionCodeOverride"

What is the correct way of doing this with Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`output` actually has `ApkVariantOutputImpl` type, that has `setVersionCodeOverride(int versionCodeOverride)` method. So you just can cast `output` to this type explicitly to use this method in Kotlin:

```
(output as ApkVariantOutputImpl).versionCodeOverride = ...
```

Also, to get `abi` version, you should use this code:

```
val abi = output.filters.find { it.filterType == OutputFile.ABI }?.identifier
```

and `abi` will be `x86`, `armeabi-v7a`, etc.

After all, your code should look something like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all {
   outputs.forEach { output ->
      val newVersionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode ?: 0 * 10 + abiVersionCodes[output.filters.find { it.filterType == OutputFile.ABI }?.identifier]
      (output as ApkVariantOutputImpl).versionCodeOverride = newVersionCode
   }
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, but accesses by value not reference. I had to write it like this for it to work:
`applicationVariants.configureEach { 
        outputs.configureEach {
            (this as ApkVariantOutputImpl).versionCodeOverride = <version code to override>
        }
    }`